# How do I change the column widths of my spreadsheet using the php google api

Tags: google-sheets-api

I'm using the example given in the Google API V4 Guide example [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/batchupdate#example) modified to invoke UpdateDimensionProperties to change the width of the first column in my sheet to 200 pixels, but I get an error. Has anyone got a working example of this operation?

```
public function setColumWidths($spreadsheetID, $sheetId) {        
    $dimensionRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionRange([
        'sheetId' => $sheetId,
        'dimension' => 'COLUMNS',
        'startIndex' => 1,
        'endIndex' => 1        
    ]);

    $dimensionProperties = new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionProperties([
        'hiddenByFilter' => false,
        'hiddenByUser' => false,
        'pixelSize' => 200,
        'developerMetadata' => [
        ]                    
    ]);


    $requests = [
        // Change the width of the first column in the named sheetId to 200 pixels
        new Google_Service_Sheets_Request([
            'UpdateDimensionProperties' => [
                'range' => $dimensionRange,
                'properties' => $dimensionProperties,                       
                'fields' => 'pixelSize'
            ]
        ])
    ];          

    $request = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest($requests);
    $result = $this->sheetsService->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetID, $request);               
}
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest to use the quickstart code provided by the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php). In the documentation, you will have a guide how to run the sample code. Then, to manipulate the row and column width, you can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/rowcolumn#adjust_column_width_or_row_height). Also don't forget to get the `sheetId` using [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) method, since it is a requirement to the requests that you need to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must be misusing the Google_Service_Sheets_Request because coding it without this is working nicely. While it would be nice to get that part sorted out, this code works and allows me to move on:

```
public function setColumWidths($spreadsheetID, $sheetId) {

    $dimensionRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionRange([
        'sheetId' => $sheetId,
        'dimension' => 'COLUMNS',
        'startIndex' => 0,
        'endIndex' => 1        
    ]);

    $dimensionProperties = new Google_Service_Sheets_DimensionProperties([
        'pixelSize' => 200                   
    ]);

    $requestBody = [
        'requests' => [
            'updateDimensionProperties' => [
                'range' => $dimensionRange,
                'properties' => $dimensionProperties,
                'fields' => 'pixelSize'
            ]
        ]
    ];        

    $request = new Google_Service_Sheets_BatchUpdateSpreadsheetRequest($requestBody);
    $result = $this->sheetsService->spreadsheets->batchUpdate($spreadsheetID, $request);        

}
```